# Camel unit test fails with NCDFE for "TestWatcher"

Tags: java, maven, junit, apache-camel

I'm trying to get some unit tests working that extend "org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport".  When I run the tests from the mvn command line, it fails with "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/rules/TestWatcher".  I get the same error running the test in Eclipse.

From some digging, I find that this "TestWatcher" class existed at about JUnit 4.12, but it was later replaced with a "TestWatchman" class.  Our build is using JUnit 4.8.1.  It appears that one or more of our dependencies end up trying to reference this old "TestWatcher" class.

In Eclipse, just as an experiment, I tried manually adding the JUnit 4.12 jar to the end of the classpath, and with this in place, it gets past that problem.  That's clearly not a viable workaround (having both JUnit 4.8.1 and JUnit 4.12 in the classpath), but it is a bit of information.

The full stacktrace that I see is the following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project ...: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/rules/TestWatcher
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
[ERROR] at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
[ERROR] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3058)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryGetMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:61)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isSuiteOnly(JUnit3TestChecker.java:64)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isValidJUnit3Test(JUnit3TestChecker.java:59)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.accept(JUnit3TestChecker.java:54)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept(JUnit4TestChecker.java:52)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:98)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:311)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.setTestsToRun(JUnit4Provider.java:191)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.rules.TestWatcher
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR] ... 31 more
```

The "dependency:tree" output is the following (with some obscurement of my project and company):

```
[INFO] com.mycomp.proj:proj-rt-order-post:bundle:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.mycomp.proj:proj-rt-common-util:jar:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.mycomp.dets.cosc:cosc-feature:bundle:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mycomp.proj:proj-comn-utils:jar:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.mycomp.proj:proj-data-models:jar:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.mycomp.proj:proj-data-models-v2_1:jar:2.0.0-RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17.redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7.redhat-2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.camel:camel-jasypt:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.3.redhat_3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.camel:camel-cxf:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-cxf-transport:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.5.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.1.5.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2.0.redhat-10:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.1.5.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.1.5.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.1.5.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |  |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.1.5.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |  |        \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3.redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-security-oauth:jar:3.1.5.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:jar:3.1.5.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- net.oauth.core:oauth-provider:jar:20100527:compile
[INFO] |     |  |     \- net.oauth.core:oauth:jar:20100527:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.1.5.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.1.5.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3.redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.1.5.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.camel:camel-sql:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.camel:camel-cassandraql:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0.0.redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- com.github.jnr:jnr-ffi:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:native:1.2.10:runtime
[INFO] |     |     |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-x86asm:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:jar:3.0.27:compile
[INFO] |     |        \- com.github.jnr:jnr-constants:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-web:jar:3.2.16.RELEASE_1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.osgi:org.osgi.compendium:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint.annotation.api:jar:1.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-junit4:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-spi:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ops4j.pax.tinybundles:tinybundles:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |     \- biz.aQute.bnd:bndlib:jar:2.1.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-lang:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] +- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-container-karaf:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-container-remote:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-container-rbc-client:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-container-rbc:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.swissbox:pax-swissbox-core:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ops4j.pax.swissbox:pax-swissbox-lifecycle:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-net:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.6:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ops4j.pax.swissbox:pax-swissbox-framework:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.swissbox:pax-swissbox-tracker:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-exec:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-io:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-monitors:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-spi:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.karaf:apache-karaf:zip:4.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.karaf.features:framework:kar:4.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.karaf.features:base:jar:4.0.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.karaf:org.apache.karaf.main:jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.karaf:org.apache.karaf.util:jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.karaf:org.apache.karaf.exception:jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.karaf:org.apache.karaf.client:jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:jar:0.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.karaf.shell:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:jar:1.11.redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.karaf.jaas:org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules:jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.karaf.jaas:org.apache.karaf.jaas.config:jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.utils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint.api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.aries.quiesce:org.apache.aries.quiesce.api:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime:jar:0.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.7.redhat-2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.karaf.jaas:org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot:jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.karaf.diagnostic:org.apache.karaf.diagnostic.boot:jar:4.0.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.osgi:jar:3.10.2.v20150203-1939:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.framework:jar:4.4.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- jline:jline:jar:2.12.1.redhat-002:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jledit:core:jar:0.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging:pax-logging-api:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging:pax-logging-service:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.url:pax-url-aether:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.karaf.features:org.apache.karaf.features.core:jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.bundlerepository:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.karaf.shell:org.apache.karaf.shell.obr:jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.karaf.features:framework:xml:features:4.0.5:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.karaf.features:standard:xml:features:4.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.karaf.features:spring:xml:features:4.0.5:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.karaf.features:enterprise:xml:features:4.0.5:runtime
[INFO] +- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-store:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-util-property:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11.redhat-2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-blueprint:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core-xml:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-core-osgi:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jms:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.2.16.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jaxb:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-test:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:test
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:provided
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-test-blueprint:jar:2.13.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.aries:org.apache.aries.util:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.aries.proxy:org.apache.aries.proxy.impl:jar:1.0.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.aries.proxy:org.apache.aries.proxy.api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.pojosr:de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework:jar:0.2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ops4j.pax.swissbox:pax-swissbox-tinybundles:jar:1.3.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ops4j.pax.swissbox:pax-swissbox-bnd:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.configadmin:jar:1.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jackson:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.6.3:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jsonpath:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jolt:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-quartz2:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.2:provided
[INFO] |     \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.11:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-xmljson:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630187:provided
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4:provided
[INFO] |     +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2.redhat-1:provided
[INFO] |     \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:provided
[INFO] +- com.mycomp.dets.cosc.hazelcast:hazelcast-enterprise-all:jar:3.7.2:provided
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.bazaarvoice.jolt:jolt-core:jar:0.0.16:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO] +- com.bazaarvoice.jolt:json-utils:jar:0.0.16:provided
[INFO] +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.1.1:provided
[INFO] +- net.minidev:asm:jar:1.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20160810:provided
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.mycomp.aft:dme2:jar:2.8.8.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.mycomp.aft.discovery:discovery-clt:jar:5.1.3-01:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0.redhat-1:compile
[INFO] +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:1.3.8:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:jar:5.11.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:jar:1.11.0.redhat-1:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-pool:jar:5.11.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-jms-pool:jar:5.11.0.redhat-630187:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6.0.redhat-9:provided
[INFO] \- xom:xom:jar:1.2.5:provided
[INFO]    +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:provided
[INFO]    +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1:provided
[INFO]    \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:provided
[INFO]       \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:provided
```

I tried running the test with "-verbose:class" turned on, but that doesn't really give me anything of use.  I still can't tell what is trying to reference that "TestWatcher" class.

Comment: It seems to be the other way around, [`TestWatchman`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestWatchman.html) being deprecated in favour of [`TestWatcher`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) introduced in 4.9, which explains why it doesn't find it in 4.8.1. Most likely it's referenced by surefire or some other plugin but it's difficult to figure out only from your description. Any chance you can post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Can you lead me to the information you found that documents that change?

Comment: I didn't find very much info, just the javadocs I already shared in my first comment, the [release-notes](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes4.9.md) and then there's the [push request](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/commit/308768863b78f3a6345e25d7f9d35892c2de5a01#diff-298901cdb912fcdfdc5fdd931d081b4a)

Comment: Oh. duh. 4.12 is newer than 4.8.1. Duh. *Slap* *slap*

Comment: Indeed. Well then, looks like you got your answer, or at least a part of it. Enjoy a well deserved weekend.